# Poner en mayuscula la primera letra con un separador (:)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estaba intentado cambiar la posición de dos palabras separadas por un delimitador. Ejemplo:

hello:world --> world:hello

Para ello lo he hecho así:

```
combo = input(str("Please put the complete name of your combo file: "))
try:
    verify = open(combo, "r")
except:
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Something went wrong while trying to load your file.")
    doWTD()
print("loaded accounts.")
print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
with open(combo, "r") as infile:
    with open("uppercase-combos.txt", "w") as out:
        for line in infile:
                words = line.strip().split(":")[::-1]
                final = ":".join(words)
                out.write(final + "\n")
                out.write(title())

print("Done!")
```

El problema que tengo es que ahora quiero que una vez tenga el siguiente contenido en un archivo nuevo que crea el script:

world:hello

example:stack

Quiero convertir la primera letra a mayúscula y así sucesivamente con las líneas que lo continúan:

World:hello

Example:stack

He estado investigando y tengo entendido que con `.capitalize()` se puede hacer. Pero no consigo aplicarlo al código, ya que me elimina todo el contenido o bien, solo cumple con la primera parte (la reinvertida). Según lo ponga...

Ese es el primer problema, el segundo que tengo es que una vez lo tenga convertido:

World:hello

Example:stack

Al intentar volver a reinvertirlo como estaba antes (pero editado con su primera mayúscula):

hello:World

stack:Example

No consigo hacer que lo reinvierta, utilizo el mismo código pensando que debería de hacer el reverse una vez más, pero no lo hace.

**Esta era la idea más pesada y la que he intentado hacer, la otra que tenia era intentar que editara directamente la segunda parte, la que viene después del separador (:) y ponerla en mayúscula, seguro que es la opción más sencilla, pero no he encontrado nada ni como hacerlo.**

Muchísimas gracias de antemano! =)
Si tenéis alguna duda intentaré responder lo más rápido posible. Estaré al tanto de las notificaciones, mientras tanto seguiré investigando por mi cuenta. =)

Comment: más allá de la respuesta que ya te han dado, ésta línea es una redundancia: combo = input(str("Please put the complete name of your combo file: ")) , ya que input devuelve una cadena, str() está de más.

Answer (score 1):

El método capitalize retorna una copia del string line con su primer caracter en mayúscula y el resto en minúscula:

```
final=line.capitalize()
print(final)
```

Imprime para `line=world:hello`:
`World:hello`

Si aplicas tu código a "final", luego del código anterior:

```
words = final.strip().split(":")[::-1]
final = ":".join(words)
print(final)
```

Imprime:
`hello:World`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! Mañana mismo lo pruebo y te comento! =)